# UnsafeRawPointer Migration

Tags: ios, xcode, migration, swift3

I've found one nice project with 360 player on GitHub. https://github.com/iosdevzone/360Video

When I **converted** it to the last **Swift3** syntax I've got this ***error***:

"*Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' with an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutableRawPointer!)*"
and

"*Overloads for 'UnsafeMutablePointer' exist with these partially matching parameter lists: (RawPointer), (OpaquePointer), (OpaquePointer?), (UnsafeMutablePointer), (UnsafeMutablePointer?)*"

I also get this article with how to migrate but it's too hard to me to fix it by myself.
https://swift.org/migration-guide/se-0107-migrate.html

It happens in this block of code:

// MARK: - Texture

```
func loadTexture(_ image: UIImage?)
{
    guard let image = image else
    {
        return
    }

    let width = image.cgImage?.width
    let height = image.cgImage?.height
```

// there is an error!
        **let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer(calloc(Int(width! * height! * 4), sizeof(GLubyte)))**

```
    let imageColorSpace = image.cgImage?.colorSpace
    let bitmapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue)
    let gc = CGContext(data: imageData, width: width, height: height, bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 4 * width, space: imageColorSpace, bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo.rawValue)
    gc.draw(image.cgImage, in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CGFloat(width), height: CGFloat(height)))

    self.updateTexture(CGSize(width: width, height: height), imageData: imageData)
    free(imageData)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code:

```
calloc(Int(width! * height! * 4), sizeof(GLubyte))
```

returns a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`. `UnsafeMutablePointer` does not offer a initializer with argument of this type.

Instead of using `calloc`:

```
 let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer(calloc(Int(width! * height! * 4), sizeof(GLubyte)))
```

create your buffer array like this:

```
let numPixel = Int(width! * height! * 4)
let buffer = [GLubyte](repeating: 0, count: numPixel)
let imageData = UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>(mutating: buffer) as UnsafeMutablePointer<GLubyte>?
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thank you! So there will be **ptrCount** instead of **imageData**?